# Number of Represented Pixels in WPF Canvas's View Port

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

My goal from this post is that I'd like to find a way to properly set the variable `currentDisplayHeight.` The key is that I am NOT looking for the height of the view port, but the height in pixels that are represented by the canvas's view port, regardless of whatever scale they are currently being viewed at (you can zoom in and out).

So to explain the code below, if you look at the scaleFactor, it is determined by the total height of my children divided by the height of the pixels displayed in the canvas's view port. Using this to scale the view port will allow me to display all of the children.

I tried to make the code below as bare bones as possible. For simplicity, I'm assuming we can restrict scaling to only the height and disregard the width:

```
//Get current transform settings
Matrix matrix = transform.Matrix;

//Regardless of current view port position, move to Top Left corner.
matrix.OffsetX = 0;
matrix.OffsetY = 0;

int totalHeight = getTotalHeightOfCanvasChildrenInPixels();
int currentDisplayHeight = ?????????????

double scaleFactor = totalHeight / currentDisplayHeight;
matrix.Scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

//Persist changes
transform.Matrix = matrix;
```

Here is the xaml where we are getting `transform.Matrix` from

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel" Background="White" >
     <Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <MatrixTransform x:Name="transform" />
     </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```